# Set position of special characters in css

Tags: html, css, position, display

I have a little problem with set the positin of my input element. I have some code and I cant understand why my element is outside my div in my view. Please look at this:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/yzhL69fa/3/


<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
     <h3 class="panel-title" id="panel-title"> Is Super </h3>
  </div>
     <div class="panel-body">
     <input class="star-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="isSuper" name="isSuperCheckbox">
  </div>
</div>
```

When I remove `class="star-checkbox"` from my input elements I can see checkbox input in correct place(custom checkbox, but I need this as a star). But when I add this class, my element go outside my div `"panel-body"`.

Also when I add to my class: `"star-checkobox"` one think: `display: inline-grid;` then my checkobx go inside my "panel-body" but this is still out of position. 
My goal is to have this checkbox which look like star but in center of my `"panel-body"`. I dont want to padding and margins there. The best would be if my checkbox just look like star and appear in the center of my div with auto margin and auto padding. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `position : relative` to the `before` class, to position the star element. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9ygq5x1n/).

```
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

.star-checkbox {
    visibility:hidden;
    font-size:60px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.star-checkbox:before {
    color:#FF912C;
    content: "\2605";
    visibility:visible;
    position:relative;
    font-size:30px;
    top:-40px;
}
.star-checkbox:checked:before {
    color:black;
    content: "\2606";
}
```

Comment: but this star still have not correct position. Check that star have greater margin top thatn margin down. So there is no center position. You can check this in console -> check element (f12), and I dont want to change anything in other class like You did it with class "panel-body"

Comment: I've updated the answer. The star-checkbox now has `position:relative`. You can position the star however you want using `top:___; left:___`. In this case it's `top:-40px` which means, 40 pixels more to the top than it would otherwise be. If the site is responsive you might use `%` values instead of `px` values. As far as I know there is no other way to get an `after` or `before` element to be placed on top of its original element.

Comment: ok but I dont want to change my panel-body class, this is class from bootstrap and I use this in many places in application. Please notice that: if you remove class "star-checkbox" from my input, then we have default checkbox in right place without changing any other class. I dont understand why this class make my input out of panel.

Comment: That’s because the original checkbox is hidden, but not replaced by the star. The star is placed in a `:before` class. Elements in a `:before` class are always placed outside the element (literally before or after) and not on top of the element like you want. The only way to do that is by using `position:relative`. By the way, the `panel-body` is not changed!